# SQL linked words - two way relationship

Tags: sql, database-design, inner-join

Hello fellow SQLarians!

I am just trying to build a tool for managing vocabularies. In the process of thinking through the database design,
I got stuck with figuring out how exactly I could make a relationship so, that when linked both items always know from each other.
Here is my main Table VOCABULARY:

```
- [generated_id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
- [word] TEXT
- [translation] TEXT
- [pos] TEXT
- [example_sentence] TEXT
- [example_translation] TEXT
- [description] TEXT
- [related_words] ???
- [related_image] BLOB
```

So I want to give every word some related words. But when I do, I also want to automatically give this word as related word to the linked words, so I don't have to link it two times.

My first approach was an extra Table with related words, like this:

```
- [word] INTEGER
- [rel_word_1] INTEGER
- [rel_word_2] INTEGER
- [rel_word_3] INTEGER
- [rel_word_4] INTEGER
- [rel_word_5] INTEGER
...
```

But this would work two way only when I have lots of duplicate data in it, eg.:

```
Word     | rel_word_1

word     | rel_word
rel_word | word
```

How is something like this achiefed, are there best practices?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create extra Table with two column

WORD_TABLE

- [generated_id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
- [word] TEXT
- [translation] TEXT
- [pos] TEXT
- [example_sentence] TEXT
- [example_translation] TEXT
- [description] TEXT
- [related_word_group_id] INTEGER FK_RELWORDGROUP_WORD
- [related_image] BLOB

RELWORDGROUP_TABLE

- [related_word_group_id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
- [rel_words_ids] TEXT ( eg. "word_id1:word_id3:word_id5:... etc")

Answer (score 0):

you need a table for a n:m-relation with two columns:

word_id
related_word_id

you can link and backlink your words with two insert statements, that can also be applied with a trigger